Neo4j Sorting after the Union on the combined statement
I have two neo4j cypher queries.
one:
MATCH (u:ClientUser {name: 'Karthick J [Karthick.J@pfizer.com]'})--(b)-[:BRAND_TAG_RELATESTOTHETOPICTAG|BUSINESSAREA_TAG_RELATESTOTHETOPICTAG|MARKET_TAG_RELATESTOTHETOPICTAG|SKILL_TAG_HASTHERELATEDTOPICTAG|INTEREST_TAG_HASTHERELATEDTOPICTAG]->(t:Tag)<-[:CONTENTPIECE_TAG_HASTHERELATEDCONTENTKEYWORD]-(p:ContentPiece)
WHERE NOT (u)-[:CLIENTUSER_CONTENTPIECE_ISTHEAUTHORFORTHECONTENTPIECE]-(p)
WITH u, b, p, t
ORDER BY p.publishedDate DESC
WITH u, p, collect(DISTINCT b.name) AS becauseYouWorkOn, collect(DISTINCT t.name) AS hasTag
RETURN DISTINCT{
becauseYouWorkOn: becauseYouWorkOn, 
recommendedArticleTitle: p.marcelDisplayName, 
recommendedArticleId: p.contentId,
publishDate: p.publishedDate,
hasTag: hasTag,
contentType: labels(p)
} AS result

Two:
MATCH (u:ClientUser{name: 'Karthick J [Karthick.J@pfizer.com]'})-[:CLIENTUSER_BRAND_WORKSONTHEBRAND|CLIENTUSER_BUSINESSAREA_WORKSINTHEBUSINESSAREA|CLIENTUSER_MARKET_SPECIALIZESINTHEMARKET]->(b)<-[:POST_BUSINESSAREA_ISASSOCIATEDWITHTHEBUSINESSAREA|POST_BRAND_ISASSOCIATEDWITHTHEBRAND|POST_BRAND_ISASSOCIATEDWITHTHEADDITIONALBRANDS|POST_MARKET_ISASSOCIATEDWITHTHEMARKET]-(n)
WHERE NOT (u)-[:CLIENTUSER_POST_HASPUBLISHEDTHEPOST]->(n)
WITH u, b, n
ORDER BY n.publishedDate desc
WITH u, n, collect(DISTINCT b.name) as becauseYouWorkOn, collect(DISTINCT b.name) as hasTag
RETURN DISTINCT{
becauseYouWorkOn: becauseYouWorkOn, 
recommendedArticleTitle: n.title, 
recommendedArticleId: n.postId,
publishDate: n.publishedDate,
hasTag: hasTag,
contentType: labels(n)
} AS result

I want to merge both the queries return one unified list and the combined list needs to be sorted based on publishedDate.
The query I have written is:
// Query for ContentPiece
MATCH (u:ClientUser {name: 'Karthick J [Karthick.J@pfizer.com]'})--(b)-[:BRAND_TAG_RELATESTOTHETOPICTAG|BUSINESSAREA_TAG_RELATESTOTHETOPICTAG|MARKET_TAG_RELATESTOTHETOPICTAG|SKILL_TAG_HASTHERELATEDTOPICTAG|INTEREST_TAG_HASTHERELATEDTOPICTAG]->(t:Tag)<-[:CONTENTPIECE_TAG_HASTHERELATEDCONTENTKEYWORD]-(p:ContentPiece)
WHERE NOT (u)-[:CLIENTUSER_CONTENTPIECE_ISTHEAUTHORFORTHECONTENTPIECE]-(p)
WITH u, b, p, t
ORDER BY p.publishedDate DESC
WITH u, p, collect(DISTINCT b.name) AS becauseYouWorkOn, collect(DISTINCT t.name) AS hasTag, p.publishedDate AS date
RETURN {
  becauseYouWorkOn: becauseYouWorkOn, 
  recommendedArticleTitle: p.marcelDisplayName, 
  recommendedArticleId: p.contentId,
  publishDate: date,
  hasTag: hasTag,
  contentType: labels(p)
} AS result

UNION

// Query for Posts
MATCH (u:ClientUser {name: 'Karthick J [Karthick.J@pfizer.com]'})-[:CLIENTUSER_BRAND_WORKSONTHEBRAND|CLIENTUSER_BUSINESSAREA_WORKSINTHEBUSINESSAREA|CLIENTUSER_MARKET_SPECIALIZESINTHEMARKET]->(b)<-[:POST_BUSINESSAREA_ISASSOCIATEDWITHTHEBUSINESSAREA|POST_BRAND_ISASSOCIATEDWITHTHEBRAND|POST_BRAND_ISASSOCIATEDWITHTHEADDITIONALBRANDS|POST_MARKET_ISASSOCIATEDWITHTHEMARKET]-(n)
WHERE NOT (u)-[:CLIENTUSER_POST_HASPUBLISHEDTHEPOST]->(n)
WITH u, b, n
ORDER BY n.publishedDate DESC
WITH u, n, collect(DISTINCT b.name) AS becauseYouWorkOn, collect(DISTINCT b.name) AS hasTag, n.publishedDate AS date
RETURN {
  becauseYouWorkOn: becauseYouWorkOn, 
  recommendedArticleTitle: n.title, 
  recommendedArticleId: n.postId,
  publishDate: date,
  hasTag: hasTag,
  contentType: labels(n)
} AS result
ORDER BY result.publishDate DESC

The problem with the above query is, since this is a union, it does the sorting on the first list first, and then the after union list as last.
What I want to do is sort the combined list, Post and ContentPiece combined and then sorted by publishedDate. Any help is highly appreciated.

Below is an example of OR condition in relationship. It means the person ACTED or DIRECTED the movie.
MATCH (TheMatrix { title: 'The Matrix' })<-[rel:ACTED_IN|:DIRECTED]-(person)
RETURN person.name, rel

[UPDATED]
If you wrap your UNION query in a CALL subquery, you can perform post-union processing on the combined results to sort just once.
For example:
MATCH (u:ClientUser {name: 'Karthick J [Karthick.J@pfizer.com]'}
CALL {
    // Query for ContentPiece
    WITH u
    MATCH (u)--(b)-[:BRAND_TAG_RELATESTOTHETOPICTAG|BUSINESSAREA_TAG_RELATESTOTHETOPICTAG|MARKET_TAG_RELATESTOTHETOPICTAG|SKILL_TAG_HASTHERELATEDTOPICTAG|INTEREST_TAG_HASTHERELATEDTOPICTAG]->(t:Tag)<-[:CONTENTPIECE_TAG_HASTHERELATEDCONTENTKEYWORD]-(p:ContentPiece)
    WHERE NOT (u)-[:CLIENTUSER_CONTENTPIECE_ISTHEAUTHORFORTHECONTENTPIECE]-(p)
    WITH u, p, collect(DISTINCT b.name) AS becauseYouWorkOn, collect(DISTINCT t.name) AS hasTag, p.publishedDate AS date
    RETURN {
    becauseYouWorkOn: becauseYouWorkOn, 
    recommendedArticleTitle: p.marcelDisplayName, 
    recommendedArticleId: p.contentId,
    publishDate: date,
    hasTag: hasTag,
    contentType: labels(p)
    } AS result

    UNION

    // Query for Posts
    WITH u
    MATCH (u)-[:CLIENTUSER_BRAND_WORKSONTHEBRAND|CLIENTUSER_BUSINESSAREA_WORKSINTHEBUSINESSAREA|CLIENTUSER_MARKET_SPECIALIZESINTHEMARKET]->(b)<-[:POST_BUSINESSAREA_ISASSOCIATEDWITHTHEBUSINESSAREA|POST_BRAND_ISASSOCIATEDWITHTHEBRAND|POST_BRAND_ISASSOCIATEDWITHTHEADDITIONALBRANDS|POST_MARKET_ISASSOCIATEDWITHTHEMARKET]-(n)
    WHERE NOT (u)-[:CLIENTUSER_POST_HASPUBLISHEDTHEPOST]->(n)
    WITH u, n, collect(DISTINCT b.name) AS becauseYouWorkOn, collect(DISTINCT b.name) AS hasTag, n.publishedDate AS date
    RETURN {
    becauseYouWorkOn: becauseYouWorkOn, 
    recommendedArticleTitle: n.title, 
    recommendedArticleId: n.postId,
    publishDate: date,
    hasTag: hasTag,
    contentType: labels(n)
    } AS result
}
RETURN result
ORDER BY result.publishDate DESC


This one does the job but it getting a lot more expensive.

Can we optimise a little?

I have updated my answer to remove the redundant sorts, and to also get the ClientUser node once. You might also want to create an index on ClientUser.name.
